# New line in email body

Tags: javascript

how can i add new line in my message body

like - i want to receive this format in my email box

email:

password:

instead - not this

email:  password:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function sendEmail() { 
      var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
        
      var password = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
      Email.send({ 
        Host: "smtp.gmail.com", 
        Username: "sender@email_address.com", 
        Password: "Enter your password", 
        To: 'receiver@email_address.com', 
        From: "sender@email_address.com", 
        Subject: "Sending Email using javascript", 
        Body: `Email: ${email} Password: ${password}`
      })
      .then(function (message) { 
        alert("mail sent successfully") ; 
      });
    } 
  </script>
```

Comment: Just add a linebreak to your template string? Or write `\n`, like in any other string.

Comment: try by changing your code like "Body: `Email: ${email} \r\n Password: ${password}`,"

Comment: What library are you using? what is Email object here?

Comment: `|Email: ${email} \n Password: ${password} ` not working

Comment: even this not working `Email: ${email} \r\n Password: ${password}`

Comment: am using `<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>`

Comment: smtpjs doesnt seem to support templates, or offer any documentation. 
if \n or \r\n are not working, try \\r\\n, who knows

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how this Email.send function works, but here is an example working with a *mailto* link using **%0D%0A** to indicate a new line:

```js
`mailto:receiver@email_address.com
?subject=e-mail subject
&body=Email: ${email} %0D%0A Password: ${password}`
```

Comment: as in like this `|Email: ${email} %0D%0A |Password: ${password}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can send an email in js (I tried), but `\n` or `%0D%0A` would work.

Answer (score 0):

guys you should teach your kids computer lol

this has worked for me

```
Body: `<html><h2>Header</h2><strong>Bold text</strong><br></br><em>Italic</em></html>`,
```

it format body very well